# How to change Internet Options for NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy

We have a service that runs on a Windows 2008 server under the identity of the builtin Network Service user.

The service needs to communicate with the Internet.

In our network we need to set the Proxy Server in the LAN Settings of IE, for this to work.

No problem doing it for the logged in user, but how do I do it for the Network Service user?

Comment: Does your proxy ask for authentication ? if so, you need to set exception, so your proxy won't ask for an account from this server ip

Comment: Why not using a standard AD account to execute the service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" account (well-known SID S-1-5-20) has its own HKEY_USERS subkey (HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20) where its per-user settings are stored. You could specify your proxy settings in its registry (HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings). I'm not aware of a place in the GUI that you can do this, but setting this via the registry isn't too difficult (here's [a nice introduction to the registry values associated with proxy settings](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/05/19/how-can-i-switch-between-using-a-proxy-server-and-not-using-a-proxy-server.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried this and restarted the service, but still get the same error. Does the machine need to be restarted? or maybe the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji Since you eventually accepted this answer, does that mean that it resolved the issue?